# virtualenv not working and can not be uninstalled

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am using MacOS version 10.12.4:

I try installing it and use it as the command below:

```
pip install virtualenv
python –m virtualenv virtual
```

This is my result from the terminal window:

```
Chhuon-Sahak-Thun:desktop kun$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Users/kun/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Chhuon-Sahak-Thun:desktop kun$ python –m virtualenv virtual
/Users/kun/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can’t open file ‘–m’: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Chhuon-Sahak-Thun:desktop kun$
```

Plus, I can not uninstall it:
Here is what it look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmVGO.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are typing `–m` (a unicode `EN_DASH`) instead of `-m` (an ascii hyphen/minus) in your virtualenv command. This is causing python to fail to parse it as a command option, instead trying to run  `–m` as a python script.

You can replace this:

```
python –m virtualenv virtual
```

with this:

```
python -m virtualenv virtual
```

Re: uninstalling, it looks like you need to `sudo pip uninstall virtualenv`, since you don't have permissions to remove the files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment but now I have another problem!

Comment: Using base prefix '/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86/Canopy.app/Contents'
New python executable in /Users/kun/Desktop/myblog/virtual/bin/python
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/kun/Desktop/myblog/virtual/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: The executable /Users/kun/Desktop/myblog/virtual/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/Users/kun/Desktop/myblog' (should be u'/Users/kun/Desktop/myblog/virtual')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813703/many-problems-with-pythons-virtualenv)